# VmRSS is shown as 0KB for a running Process

Tags: c++, linux, memory, rhel7

I have a C++ Server application running on **RHEL 7.0**. When the application is started the process resident memory is around `250` Megabytes. 
But after 24 hours the top command output shows the process Resident memory as 0. But the application is running and it is processing the requests received from the clients. Also the top command output shows the process state as S-sleeping. Can anyone share some of your thoughts on why the resident memory size is shown as zero even though the application is up and processing the requests received.

```
PID   USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
25437 root      20   0  2472772     0     0  S  60.2  0.0   1622:27 test
```

Comment: What the `htop` says?

Comment: Actually this is an production environment where we cannot install htop

Comment: It is hard to say, since the top command does not show the swapped memory for each process. Inspect manually the `/proc/PID/{status,smaps}`. Also keep in mind that the virtual memory = resident memory + swapped pages.